# PHP using iconv to convert large files

Tags: php, performance, file, large-files, iconv

I need to convert text files' character encodings without hogging the server's memory, while the input file is user configured and its size isn't limited.

Would it be more efficient to wrap an unix's iconv command using exec() (which I'd rather avoid, although I already use it in the application for other file operations), or should I read the file line by line and output it into another file?

I'm thinking working this way:

```
$in = fopen("in.txt", "r");
$out = fopen("out.txt", "w+");
while(($line = fgets($in, 4096)) !== false) {
    $converted = iconv($charset["in"], $charset["out"], $line);
    fwrite($out, $converted);
}
rename("out.txt", "in.txt");
```

Is there any better approach to convert the file fast and efficiently? I'm thinking this might be rather CPU intensive, but then I believe iconv itself is an expensive task so I'm not sure if I can make it actually not eat the server much at all.

Thanks!

Comment: why don't you try both ways, and compare speed and memory load?

Comment: Just playing with it right now, though the testing data I have do not represent the production well enough as the size and form of that data will vary between requests so I was wondering if there's some general idea about how to handle that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, 
thanks for the input, I did "my homework" based on it and got the results, working with 50MB sample of actual CSV data:

First, iterating over the file using PHP:

```
$in = fopen("a.txt", "r");
$out = fopen("p.txt", "w+");

$start = microtime(true);

while(($line = fgets($in)) !== false) {
    $converted = iconv("UTF-8", "EUC-JP//TRANSLIT", $line);
    fwrite($out, $converted);
}

$elapsed = microtime(true) - $start;
echo "<br>Iconv took $elapsed seconds\r\n";
```

> Iconv took 2.2817220687866 seconds

That's not so bad I guess, so I tried the exact same approach in #bash, so it wouldn't have to load all the file but iterate over each line instead (which might not exactly happen as I understand what Lajos Veres answered). Indeed, this method wasn't exactly efficient (CPU was under a heavy load all the time). Also, the output file is smaller than the other 2, although after a quick look it looks the same, so I must have made a mistake in the bash script, however, that shouldn't have such effect on performance anyway:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "" > b.txt
time echo $(
    while read line
    do
        echo $line |iconv -f utf-8 -t EUC-JP//TRANSLIT >> b.txt
    done < a.txt
)
```

> real    9m40.535s
>   user    2m2.191s
>   sys     3m18.993s

And then the classic approach which I would have expected to hog the memory, however, checking the CPU/Memory usage, it didn't seem to take any more memory than any other approach, therefore being a winner:

```
#!/bin/bash
time echo $(
    iconv -f utf-8 -t EUC-JP//TRANSLIT a.txt -o b2.txt
)
```

> real    0m0.256s
>   user    0m0.195s
>   sys     0m0.060s

I'll try to get a bigger file sample to test the 2 more efficient methods to make sure the memory usage doesn't get significant, however, the result seems obvious enough to assume the single pass through the whole file in bash is the most efficient (I didn't try that in PHP, as I believe loading an entire file to an array/string in PHP isn't ever a good idea).

Answer (score 1):

fyi:
http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=6050

Anyway the os needs to read the whole file sooner or later. It means when it reads the cache purging lru-like logic will free up memory. lru means probably older pages will be throwed out.

You cant be 100% sure how your system will tolerate this. You have to separate this process with a different hw or virtualizaton but these solutions can also create bottlenecks.

Prudential testing is probably the most cost effectice way. But not the implementation can cause most of the headaches rather the expected workload.

I mean processing lots of g files in hundred paralell thread is totally different than a few files/day.

Comment: That's good to know, thanks! So I'll compare the whole file load to the 2 scripts Dalim posted and see how it compares on our development enviroment with some sample data (although it is an interface to transfer pretty much any file, so it can be really anything, any size, line length).

Answer (score 1):

This is benchmarking for Iconv with PHP and Iconv with Unix Bash.

For PHP ->

```
<?php
$text = file('a.txt');
$text = $text[0];
$start = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
 $str =  iconv("UTF-8", "EUC-JP", $text);
}
$elapsed = microtime(true) - $start;
echo "<br>Iconv took $elapsed seconds\r\n";
?>
```

Depends on my server results,

```
root@ubuntu:/var/www# php benc.php
<br>Iconv took 0.0012350082397461 seconds
```

For Unix Bash ->

```
#!/bin/bash
begin_time=$(($(date +%N)/10000000))
for i in {0..1000}
 do
      iconv -f utf-8 -t EUC-JP a.txt -o b.txt
 done
end_time=$(($(date +%s%N)/1000000))
total_time=$((end_time-begin_time))
echo ${total_time}
```

Depends on my server results,

```
root@ubuntu:/var/www#bash test.sh
1380410308211
```

Results clearly say that you get more performance from iConv with PHP in CPU usage percentage. It's point out that, the winner use memory less as CPU.

Note: If you run, you should create and a.txt file in same dictionary with ***.sh and ***.php files.

Comment: Thanks, playing with that, although the bash time wasn't giving me correct time, changing both times to `$(($(date +%s%N)/1000000))` fixes that. However, the bash also writes the output, which might put it into a disadvantage, I'll compare on a few servers how does it do with writing the output as well.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just do it in the system rather than reading the file chunk by chunk. Given that `iconv` exists in your system

```
system(sprintf('iconv -f %s -t %s %s > %s',
                $charset['in'], $charset['out'], "in.txt", "out.txt"));
```